# Relative Gain Array of a singular matrix

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I am a masters student in controls and would like to get insight into the concept of relative gain array for multivariable feedback control. In general what I have come across from the book on the same topic by Skogestad and Postlethwaite, relative gain array element $\lambda_{i,j}$ is given by $G_{i,j}G^{-1}_{j,i}$, where G is a square matrix.

But how to find it if the matrix G is not invertible? In this case the matrix is
$G = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$. Is there a different approach I can take, a different definition perhaps to calculate the RGA?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @ J.W. Perry and Jesse P Fransis - Thanks for the inpiut

Comment: A matrix is singular if and only if its determinant is zero.

Comment: @Zero, first of all, thank you for adding more details! If you see, we could answer your question more accurately and easily! If you want to read more, see [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)!

Comment: @ Jesse P Francis  @J.W. Perry ... Apologies but I couldn't understand the reference...Is there something wrong with my understanding of a singular matrix as put in the question?...G has zero determinant in this case.

Comment: @ J.W. Perry...since a singular matrix is not invertible that is the reason I posted this question. What I meant from the question was that the book defines RGA using an inverse, so what if the inverse doesn't exist? I meant for others to provide a way around the problem of singularity...Thank you for putting so much thought in the question...I'll try to frame it appropriately the next time...cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Moore-Pensrose pseudoinverse can be used to approximate for some properties of inverse in this case.

Comment: You are correct. I believe it also is stated in the book of Skogestad and Postlethwaite.

Comment: @WG...the one that I came across in the book is for rectangular matrices. I applied the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse but it didn't give me any information regarding the interaction. Moreover it doesn't satisfy one essential property of RGA - sum of rows is unity. Much like some information is still not there using this inverse...However I came to the conclusion that for singular matrices it is not possible to calculate RGA. I'll be happy to know what you think about it!

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\dss{\mathop{\bigodot}\limits}
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}\def\F{{\cal F}}\def\G{{\cal G}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\abs#1{\operatorname{abs}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07334), Jeffrey Uhlmann makes a compelling case that the correct inverse to use in these situations **IS NOT** the Moore-Penrose inverse but rather a unit-consistent pseudoinverse.

Such an inverse is invariant under a rescaling of rows and/or columns. These scalings take the form of multiplication by diagonal matrices.

I'll denote the *Unit-Consistent* (or Uhlmann) or U-inverse using a "\cup" superscript.
The invariance property is
$$\eqalign{
A &= \Diag{a}, &\;B = \Diag{b} \\
X^\cup &= B\LR{AXB}^\cup A
  \quad&\implies\quad \LR{AXB}^\cup = B^{-1}X^\cup A^{-1} \\
}$$
which is the analog of an identity involving unitary matrices
$$\eqalign{
I &= R^HR, &\;I = Q^HQ \\
X^\cup &= R\LR{QXR}^\cup Q
  \quad&\implies\quad \LR{QXR}^\cup = R^HX^\cup Q^H \\
}$$
Like other reflexive inverses, $X^\cup$ satisfies the first two Penrose conditions
$$\eqalign{
X &= XX^\cup X, \qquad\quad X^\cup = X^\cup XX^\cup  \\
\\
}$$

---

Here is a simplified algorithm for calculating the U-inverse
$$\eqalign{
X,&J,L,M \;\in\;\bbR{m\times n} \\
J,&\o
  \qquad &\big({\rm all\,ones\;matrix\;and\;vector}\big) \\
L &= \log(\abs{X})
  \qquad &\big({\rm elementwise\;functions}\big) \\
M &= \fracLR{\o^TL\o}{2mn}J - L \\
A &= \Diag{\exp\fracLR{M\o}{n}} \\
B &= \Diag{\exp\fracLR{M^T\o}{m}} \\
X^\cup &= B\LR{AXB}^+A \in\bbR{n\times m}
  \qquad &\big({\rm Uhlmann\;inverse}\big) \\
}$$
where "+" superscript denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse.

This algorithm works well, as long as no elements are **exactly** zero.

Uhlmann has written a robust (but complicated) algorithm to handle such cases.

An interesting property of the $(Y=AXB)$ matrix used in the algorithm is the following
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \m{y_1&y_2&\ldots}
\quad&\implies\quad Z=\log(Y) = \m{z_1&z_2&\ldots} \\
0 &= Z\o = \sum_{j=1}^n z_j
   \quad&\implies\quad \o = y_1\odot y_2\odot\ldots
   \;\equiv\; \dss_{j=1}^n Ye_{j} \\
0 &= Z^T\o
   \quad&\implies\quad \o = \dss_{i=1}^m Y^Te_{i} \\
}$$
This is the product-wise analog of the doubly-stochastic property.

The **Relative Gain Array** for a rectangular (or singular) matrix can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
RGA(X) = X \odot \LR{X^\cup}^T \\
}$$
**NB**: The U-inverse is unique but not involutory,
so in general
$$\eqalign{
X \ne \LR{X^\cup}^\cup \\
}$$
However, if $X$ is invertible then $X^\cup=X^{-1}$ which is (of course) involutory.

$$\eqalign{
}$$